# Right Click -Selenium - Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, contextmenu

I'm little bit struggling to find the correct way to perform a right click.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
click_Menu = driver.find_element_by_id("Menu")
print(click_Menu.text)
action.move_to_element(click_Menu)
action.context_click(on_element=click_Menu)
action.perform()
```

All the imports are there.And
`print(click_Menu.text`) => returns "Menu", so the element has been found

Error :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

I tried to add `time.sleep()` but the result is the same.

Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 1):

This code will help you to solve the issue.

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
```

**Identifying the source element**

```
click_Menu= driver.find_element_by_xpath("your path")
```

or

```
click_Menu= driver.find_element_by_id("Menu")
```

**Action chain object creation**

```
action = ActionChains(driver)
```

**Right-click operation and then perform**

```
action.move_to_element(click_Menu).perform()
action.context_click(click_Menu).perform()
```

**The easy way to overcome many of these types of errors is to just add some sort of delay:**

```
import time
time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. i will keep trying

Comment: @Hadj Can you try with time to sleep? The easy way to overcome many of these types of errors is to just add some sort of delay. import time time.sleep(2)

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to pass only the element within `context_click()` as follows:

```
context_click(click_Menu)
```

Your effective line of code will be:

```
action.context_click(click_Menu)
```

Optimizing your code block:

```
click_Menu = driver.find_element(By.ID, "Menu")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(click_Menu).context_click(click_Menu).perform()
```

Comment: @Hadj Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found.

I was using an old ActionChains object. So i reinstantiate it by creating a new one.

```
action1 = ActionChains(driver)
```